# Application level number format asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my application I have many properties like

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=false,ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false,DataFormatString="{0:0.00}")]
public decimal somedecimalvalue { get; set; }
```

Is there any way i can generalize this whenever a decimal property is created above format is applied to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually assign metadata for decimal properties in your models by creating custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`:

```
public class DecimalMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (propertyName == null)
            return metadata;

        if (metadata.ModelType == typeof(decimal))
        {
            // Given DisplayFormat Attribute:

            // if ApplyFormatInEditMode = true 
            // metadata.EditFormatString = "{0:0.00}";

            // for DataFormatString
            metadata.DisplayFormatString = "{0:0.00}";

            // for ConvertEmptyStringToNull
            metadata.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false;
        }

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

And then register this provider in *Global.asax.cs* in `Application_Start()` method:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DecimalMetadataProvider();
```

Then you can remove `DisplayFormat` attribute from decimal properties. Note that this won't affect other properties and you can safely add other data annotations on your decimal properties.

Read more about [MetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee407408%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class and its properties.

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand exactly what you wanted to know. describe some more

I think there is no direct feature to do that. How about having one Interface and implement the same for all your entities?

Comment: I don't want to add displayformat attribute line to each of my decimal type value. this should be somewhere in resource file or somewhere else. this should be rather a comment not an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check out using *Model Templates*.

If you want to customize the way in which the decimal is displayed throughout the application then you have to create a partial view named *decimal.cshtml* (if Razor) and store it in the *Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates* folder.

In the decimal.cshtml you can control the way in which the model decimal is being displayed.

Like that, to customize the way in which it is displayed for editing then you have to create another view with the same name and dump it into the *Views/Shared/EditorTemplates* folder.

The MVC framework takes care of the remaining things.

Ex.

**Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/decimal.cshtml**

```
@model decimal
<p>
  @Model.ToString("0.00")
</p>
```

Comment: I know about the displayfor template and editorfor template but there are scenrios like third party grids where again i ve to control the display by myself